# Turnaround time within continuous dates starting from today

Tags: days, continuous

I have a table called **Sales** and it looks like this:

```
Item.....SaleDate..
-------------------
A........2017-08-11
A........2017-08-10
B........2017-08-11
B........2017-08-10
A........2017-08-09
A........2017-08-01
A........2017-07-31
C........2017-06-01
D........2017-08-11
```

What I am trying to get is the number of continuous days an item is sold ending with today (2017-08-11)

So in this case the result set should be

```
Item.....Days..
---------------
A........3        (from 9th to 11th)
B........2        (10th and 11th)
D........1        (only 11th)
```

(and no record of C because there was no sale on the 11th)

No matter what I tried I cannot seem to get the final result.
Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please give the language you are using, and add it to the tags. `Days` and `continuous` are not appropriate tags for this question.

Comment: I improved the formatting of the table and fixed some minor grammar issues.